# Indentation of XSL without affecting transformed output

Tags: xslt

Is it possible to indent an xsl stylesheet without affecting the amount of whitespace in output *plaintext* file. I have

```
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
```

and things like

```
<xsl:template match="author">
    <xsl:value-of select="@surname" />
    <xsl:if test="count(g)&gt;1">, <xsl:for-each select="g">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,1)" />.<xsl:if test="position()!=last()">\,</xsl:if></xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

But I would like to format the code as

```
<xsl:template match="author">
    <xsl:value-of select="@surname" />
    <xsl:if test="count(g)&gt;1">,
        <xsl:for-each select="g">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,1)" />.
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">\,</xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

However, this does not work, since some whitespaces are preserved, and that breaks causes trouble with the target program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xsl:text` to wrap the plain text you want to output.

```
<xsl:template match="author">
    <xsl:value-of select="@surname" />
    <xsl:if test="count(g)&gt;1">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="g">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,1)" />
            <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>\,<xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Will it swallow all other whitespace (not within xsl:text) then?

Comment: @user877329 - All other whitespace is now insignificant because all of the elements now either contain element(s) or text; not both. This allows the processor to ignore this whitespace because it is not part of the actual output.

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace in the stylesheet is significant only if one of the following conditions applies:

1. it is within an `xsl:text` element
2. it is part of the same text node as non-whitespace characters (as in your example)
3. there is an `xml:space="preserve"` attribute.